# finding object by class and fade another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a class id of .icon informationIcon.  When I "mouseleave" i want the redNotesDiv(which is on the same page) to fade.  Right now, this code does not trigger. I've looked at examples, and it seems as though it should work. What is the problem?

```
$(".icon informationIcon").bind("mouseleave", function () {
    redNotesDiv.fadeOut("slow", "linear")
});
```

ASPX. File

```
<div class="icon informationIcon" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe your JavaScript executes before your HTML is loaded? Maybe wrap your JavaScript in a [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: Is 'redNotesDiv' a class?

Comment: @AakashVerma Yes. It's redNotes2

Comment: What is redNotes2? I mean to say is it a div class or something like that similar to `icon informationIcon`?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate; he might be trying to access a class made of more than one word for which the hack seems the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".icon.informationIcon").bind("mouseleave", function () {
    redNotesDiv.fadeOut("slow", "linear")
});
```

In the selector the classes should not have space and each class should have (dot.)operator

Answer (score 0):

Should with the following format when you want to select element with multiple classes:

```
$(".class1.class2.class3")

# your code should be
$(".icon.informationIcon").bind("mouseleave", function () {
    redNotesDiv.fadeOut("slow", "linear")
});
```

Comment: Your example is correct too

Comment: @jan86 In fact my answer is earlier than the accepted :-(.  Anyway, solve  your problem is the first thing.